# Controlling Camera Exposure and Iso value

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm trying to capture absolute radiance values on surfaces by using the google tango dev kit. Therefore, I need to know at which exposure/iso settings the camera is currently working. As far as I know, there are a few settings I can pass with the config before connecting to the service.

My first problem is that I'm not able to set these properties.. I found another post ([Does setting exposure/ISO in Google Tango config work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058811/does-setting-exposure-iso-in-google-tango-config-work)) and just used his code to change my config. But the first call already fails and returns -2 (TANGO_INVALID):

```
TangoConfig_setBool(m_config, "config_color_mode_auto", false);
```

Do you have any idea why this fails. I enabled config_enable_color_camera, too. Everything is done before connecting to the service.

The next Issues I'm facing are:

- How to alter the exposure settings without reconnecting to the service?
- Is there a proper way to query the exposure and iso value while config_color_mode_auto is enabled?

Thanks very much! Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On current release, Tango are on a new platform,which the "config_color_mode_auto" is always set as true,even you switch it to off.
meaning that you may not be able to set it manually anymore.
Google already aware the issues. just be patient.
Google is working on it.

Comment: 4 months later.. how are things going? ;)

Comment: i recently added a new post related to this problem..(may containing a possible way to address it) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160946/precise-control-of-a-rgb-camera-settings